# BLToolkit + T4 generation + MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, t4, bltoolkit

I receive an exception running my T4 template:

```
Running transformation: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingB9C41E12E53D4F3972EB874C0B96FDFD.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConnection()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingB9C41E12E53D4F3972EB874C0B96FDFD.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadServerMetadata()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingB9C41E12E53D4F3972EB874C0B96FDFD.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadMetadata()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingB9C41E12E53D4F3972EB874C0B96FDFD.GeneratedTextTransformation.GenerateModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingB9C41E12E53D4F3972EB874C0B96FDFD.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)
```

this is my T4 file:

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5"         #>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs"   #>
<#@ include file="BLToolkit.ttinclude" #>
<#@ include file="MySql.ttinclude"    #>
<#
    ConnectionString     = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=accounting;Uid=root;pwd=1;";
    DataProviderAssembly = @"D:\Temp\BLToolKitMySql\BLToolKitMySql\mysql.data.dll";

    Namespace       = "BLToolKitMySql";
    DataContextName = "DataModel";
    GenerateModel();
#>
```

I added all references like: BLtoolkit.3 , Bltoolkit.Data.DataProvider.MySql3 , mysql.data , sys.data.linq and MySqlDataProvider.cs

Comment: What's the exception and what's the actual line of code?

Comment: there is no information about above error.no file name ,no project name, just line 1 and column 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the MySQL connection can't be instanciated.
I had to correct the MySql.ttinclude file : changed

> ConnectionType = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, **MySql.Data**";

to

> ConnectionType = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, **mysql.data**";